# Why isn't X-Request-ID or X-Correlation-ID considered a standard HTTP header?

Tags: http, http-headers

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) the two mentioned request/correlation id headers aren't standard. As far as I know they are extremely helpful in tracing API requests from client to server (and additional applications).

I have seen this recommended to be used in may articles online - yet it's not an official standard.

Is there some reason that this shouldn't be used?

Answer (score 1):

*If* these headers are good for general use, it simply means that nobody has gone through the trouble of standardizing them. Anyone can pick this up, but someone has to.